# Bat redirecting stderr to stdout has weird behaviour

Tags: batch-file, stdout, redirect, stderr

I have a bat script which at one point redirects the stderr of a process to the stdout, and then writes it to a file. I used to do it like this:

```
process.exe 2>&1 > file.txt
```

However, this doesn't redirect the stderr to the file ( for reasons I can't understand ). When I modified the line to :

```
process.exe > file.txt 2>&1
```

The whole thing worked. Aren't these two equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first example essentially does:

```
stderr = stdout;
stdout = "file.txt";
```

So, `stderr` is still pointing at the original `stdout`. Your second example does:

```
stdout = "file.txt";
stderr = stdout;
```

So, both `stderr` and `stdout` now reference `file.txt`. It's annoyingly subtle.

Answer (score 2):

The redirection `2>&1` works at the end of the command line. It will not work as the first redirection parameter, the redirection requires a filename and the `2>&1` at the end. You're effectively trying to redirect stderr but there is no placeholder to store the stderr messages hence it failed. The shortcut to remembering this is

```
executable  > some_file 2>&1
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, for reasons I do not completely understand, a think like

```
process.exe > result.txt 2<&1
```

also seems to work